# What are the names of the 48 followers of Ramanujacharya?

Tags: ramanujacharya

As far as I know, Ramanuja had 48 followers. What are the names of these 48 disciples of Ramanujacharya? Please provide their pictures, if available.

Comment: Ramanujacharya had 74 disciples, called the Simhasanadhipatis. Where did you get the number 48 from?

Comment: Sir what do you know about Ramanjur please do not say like this under Ramacharya there where 48 follwers it is real

Comment: Where did you get the 48 number from?

Comment: @L.AravindKalaimani I have answered your question below. If you are satisfied with the answer, you may mark it as ‘accepted’ by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer. If you find a later answer better, you may mark that one as accepted instead of this one.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea where you got the number 48, from, but Swami Ramanuja appointed 74 of his disciples as Simhasana-adipatis to carry on the SriVaishnsva Sampradaya as he had established. (Other disciples are also mentioned below)

The names of the 74 Simhasana-adipatis are (Courtesy: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33224/15963):

> 1. Chottai Nambi, son of Aalavandaar
> 2. Pundarika, son of Periya Nambigal (Mahapurna)
> 3. Yaamuna, son of Thirugottiyur Nambigal (Goshtipurna)
> 4. Sundarabaahu, son of Maalaa dhaara
> 5. Raamaanuja, son of Thirumalai Nambigal (Sailapurna)
> 6. Paraasara Bhattar and his brother Vedavyaasa Bhattar, sons of Kuratthaazhwaan
> 7. Raamaanuja, son of Mudaliaandaan
> 8. Madhyamaarya (Naduvil Aazhwaan)
> 9. Gomathaarya
> 10. Tirukkovalur Aazhwaan
> 11. Tiru Mohur Aazhwaan
> 12. Pillai Aazhwaan
> 13. Varada Vishnu Acharya
> 14. Vishnu Chitta (Engalaazhwaan)
> 15. Marichyaarya (Milagaazhwaan)
> 16. Neyyundaazhwaan
> 17. Baalaarya I (Setlur Siriyaazhwaan)
> 18. Ananthaarya (Ananthaazhwan)
> 19. Vedaanthi Aazhwaan
> 20. Kovil Aazhwaan
> 21. Utkalaarya (Ukkalaazhwaan)
> 22. Haranaapuraarya (Arana Purathu Aazhwaan)
> 23. Govinda Bhattar (Embaar)
> 24. Pranatha Arthi hara (Kidaambi Aachaan)
> 25. Baalaarya II (Kaniyanur Siriya Aazhwaan)
> 26. Ichchambaadi Aachaan
> 27. Kongil Aachaan
> 28. Ichchambaadi Jeeyar
> 29. Nallaan of Tirupathi (Tirumalai Nallaan)
> 30. Sattaam Pillai Jeeyar
> 31. Tiru Vellarai Jeeyar
> 32. Aatkondavalli Jeeyar
> 33. Tirunagarip Pillai
> 34. Kaaraanji Somayaaji
> 35. Alamkaara Venkatavar
> 36. Nambi Karum Devar
> 37. Devaraaja Bhattar
> 38. Pillai Urandai Udaiyaar
> 39. Tirukkurugai Piraan Pillanan
> 40. Vallalaar (Periya Koil Vallalaar)
> 41. Aasoorip Perumaal
> 42. Kannapurathu Aachchaan
> 43. Munip Perumaal
> 44. Ammanghip Perumaal
> 45. Maruthi, The Elder (Maruthi Andaan)
> 46. Maruthi, The Younger (Maruthi Siriya Andaan)
> 47. Sri Rama Krathu Nathaarya (Somayaji Aandaan)
> 48. Jeeyar Aandaan
> 49. Isvaraandaan
> 50. Iyunnip Pillai Aandaan
> 51. Periyaandaan
> 52. Andaan, The younger (Siriyaandaan)
> 53. Aandaan, The younger of Kurinji Puram
> 54. Ammangi Aandaan
> 55. Aalavandaar Aandaan
> 56. Devaraaja Muni (Arulaalap Perumal Emperumaanaar)
> 57. Thondanoor Nambi
> 58. Marudoor Nambi
> 59. Mazhuvoor Nambi
> 60. Tiruk Kurungudi Nambi
> 61. Kuruva Nambi
> 62. Mudumbai Nambi
> 63. Andhra Purna (Vaduga Nambi)
> 64. Vanki purathu Nambi
> 65. Paraankusa Nambi
> 66. Ammangi Ammaal
> 67. Varadaarya (Paruthik Kollai Ammaal)
> 68. Utkala Ammaal
> 69. Chottai Ammaal
> 70. Mudumbai Ammaal
> 71. Komaandoor Pillai
> 72. Komaandoor Ilayavalli
> 73. Kidaambi Perumal
> 74. Aarkaattup Pillaan

Details of the 74 Simhasana-adipatis are given in https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=nov2000%2F0044.html

Apart from these, Swami Ramanuja also had two main disciples Kuresha (Kuratthaazhwaan/Aazhwaan) and Dasharathi (Mudaliaandaan/Aandaan). Kuratthaazhwaan sons Parasara Bhattar and Vedavyasa Bhattar were also Swami Ramanuja’s disciples, but they are already mentioned in the list of the 74 Simhasana-adipatis (See No.6).

Swami also initiated his cousin (his mother’s elder brother’s son (Thirumalai Nambi’s son) ) whose Sanskrit name is Govinda Bhattar, and Tamil name is Embar. He is the immediate next Acharyan after Swami Ramanuja in the Acharya Ratna Haaram. You can see it in the image below (Embar is circled).

[image: Acharya Ratna Haaram]

Also, note that Embar is also one of the 74 Simhasana-adipatis (in the above list, he is no.23)

Ramanujacharya also had another disciple called Dhanurdasa, who was originally very much attached to his wife, because of her beautiful eyes, but when Swami Ramanuja showed him the beauty of Sri Ranganatha’s eyes, he immediately surrendered to Ramanuja along with his wife.

Thus, Swami Ramanujacharya had the 74 Simhasana-adipatis as disciples, along with Kuratthazhwan, Mudaliandan, and Dhanurdasa. Also, Ramanuja has many other disciples whose names are not prominently known, thus, an exhaustive list of all his disciples can never be made.

Comment: If possible please answer his other question too!! He is looking for these answers since long time and keeps repeating questions same!! Nice to see your answer!

Comment: @AkshayS when he asked the same question for the third time yesterday, I realised how desperate he was, and so, I tried to answer it to my best... :)

Comment: @AkshayS unfortunately I am not aware of all the disciples of Yamunacharya... I know only 3-4... :((

Comment: Answer what you can please. He is so eager for those answers!!!!