# 74 simhasana-adhipathi established by Sri Ramanuja-acharya?

Tags: ramanujacharya

Sri Ramanuja-acharya, over 1000 years ago, established 74 peetas / simhasana-adhipathis i.e. acharyas qualified to do pancha-samskara and propound path of bhakthi, sarangathi & mukti (devotion, surrender & salvation) to Sri Vishnu (Bhagavan/Para-Brahman/Param-Atma/God).

Who were the 74 originally? Who are present today?

Comment: To add to this, my Acharyan, a Jeeyar recently organized a summit of all of the Acharya Purushas in Srirangam. It was found that 37 of the 74 families are still continuing with the Acharya Purusha paramparai. The rest have either joined as sishyas of another thirumaligai or have taken initiation under a Jeeyar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This site](http://jetuk.org/statueofequality/74-simhasinadhipathis/) has compiled the complete list of the 74 simhasana-adhipathis appointed by Sripad Ramanujacharya:

> 1. Chottai Nambi, son of Aalavandaar
> 2. Pundarika, son of Maha purna
> 3. Yaamuna, son of Goshti purna
> 4. Sundara bahu, son of Maalaa dhaara
> 5. Raamaanuja, son of Saila purna
> 6. Paraasara Bhattar (and his brother, sons of Aalvaan)
> 7. Raamaanuja, son of Aandaan
> 8. Madhyamaarya (Naduvil Aazhwaan)
> 9. Gomathaarya
> 10. Tiruk Kovalur Aazhwaan
> 11. Tiru Mohur Aazhwaan
> 12. Pillai Aazhwaan
> 13. Varada Vishnu Acharya
> 14. Vishnu Chittha
> 15. Marichyaarya (Milagaazhwaan)
> 16. Neyyundaazhwaan
> 17. Baalaarya – I (Setlur Siriyaazhwaan)
> 18. Ananthaarya (Ananthaazhwan)
> 19. Vedaanthi Aazhwaan
> 20. Kovil Aazhwaan
> 21. Utkalaarya (Ukkalaazhwaan)
> 22. Haranaapuraarya (Arana Purathu Aazhwaan)
> 23. Govinda bhattar (Embaar)
> 24. Pranatha Arthi hara (Kidaambi Aachaan)
> 25. Baalaarya II (Kaniyanur Siriya Aazhwaan)
> 26. Ichchambaadi Aachaan
> 27. Kongil Aachaan
> 28. Ichchambaadi Jeeyar
> 29. Nallaan of Tirupathi (Tirumalai Nallaan)
> 30. Sattaam Pillai Jeeyar
> 31. Tiru Vellarai Jeeyar
> 32. Aatkondavalli Jeeyar
> 33. Tirunagarip Pillai
> 34. Kaaraanji Somayaaji
> 35. Alamkaara Venkatavar
> 36. Nambi Karum Devar
> 37. Devaraaja Bhattar
> 38. Pillai Urandai Udaiyaar
> 39. Pillan (Tiruk Kurugai Piraan Pillanan)
> 40. Vallalaar (Periya Koil Vallalaar)
> 41. Aasoorip Perumaal
> 42. Aachchaan of Kannapura (Kannapurathu Aachchaan)
> 43. Munip Perumaal
> 44. Ammanghip Perumaal
> 45. Maruthi, The Elder (Maruthi Andaan)
> 46. Martuhi, The Younger (Maruthi Siriya Andaan)
> 47. Sri Rama Krathu nathaarya (Somayaji Aandaan)
> 48. Jeeyar Aandaan
> 49. Isvaraandaan
> 50. Iyunnip Pillai Aandaan
> 51. Periyaandaan
> 52. Andaan, The younger (Siriyaandaan)
> 53. Aandaan, the younger of Kurinji Puram
> 54. Ammangi Aandaan
> 55. Aalavandaar Aandaan
> 56. Devaraaja Muni (Arulaalap Perumal Emperumaanaar)
> 57. Thondanoor Nambi
> 58. Marudoor Nambi
> 59. Mazhuvoor Nambi
> 60. Tiruk Kurum Kudi Nambi
> 61. Kuruva Nambi
> 62. Mudumbai Nambi
> 63. Andhra Purna (Vaduga Nambi)
> 64. Vanki purathu Nambi
> 65. Paraankusa Nambi
> 66. Ammangi Ammaal
> 67. Varadaarya (Paruthik Kollai Ammaal)
> 68. Utkala Ammaal
> 69. Chottai Ammaal
> 70. Mudumbai Ammaal
> 71. Komaandoor Pillai
> 72. Komaandoor Ilayavalli
> 73. Kidaambi Perumal
> 74. Pillaan of Arcot (Aarkaattup Pillaan)